# MISRA C 11.2 violation: Conversions shall not be performed between a pointer to an incomplete type and any other type

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have array that are declared in a header file call array.h, defined in a file array.c and used in an other file called main.c.

Here a code snippet of those files.
array.h

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16  Identifier;
    uint16  Data;

} array_struct_type ;
extern const array_struct_type myarray[];
```

array.c where the array is initialize looks like this

```
const array_struct_type myarray[] =
{
    {0x01u, 0u},
    {0x01u, 0u},
}
```

main.c

```
#include "array.h"
static array_struct_type * pArray;
pArray = myarray;
```

When passing the address of the array to a pointer I got a MISRA C violation 11.2: Conversions shall not be performed between a pointer to an incomplete type and any other type

I tried the following

```
pArray = (array_struct_type * )myarray;
pArray = &myarray[0];
```

The only way I found to fix this is to disable MISRA pragma while affecting the pointer. There must be a better solution.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: How does your code know how big this array is?

Comment: Possible aside: you seem to be discarding the `const` in your assignment.

Comment: Detail: "When passing the address of the array to a pointer I got a ..." is amiss.  `pArray = myarray;` does not take the address of the array and assign it to `pArray`.  That would be `pArray = &myarray;`.  `pArray = myarray;` assigns the address of the first element of the array to `pArray`.

Comment: Jee, why code `static array_struct_type * pArray;` and not `static const array_struct_type * pArray;` if looking to assign to a `const` type?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, you are right the code does not know the size of this array.